# Pub error: Pub build failed, [255] Wrong script snapshot version

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have started getting this issue now after going through a lot of "chaos" with performing a system restore (I'm on Win8.1) while trying to get a certain game working again. Now that that mess is over and done with, I have been left with a few apps and such removed and needing to be reinstalled, including the JDK which I have already reinstalled. Since I have a project I need to work on I opened up DartEditor again and when I tried to do `pub build` I get this error:

```
Pub build failed, [255] Wrong script snapshot version, expected  
'f6711525cff9f7d0d08595166664b767' found '836a274342f7f88d6b5a9bb59b2649a9'
```

Googling led me to this old [issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20565#makechanges) but that's labelled as fixed...what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried using a different JDK?

Comment: Have you tried `pub cache repair` and delete the `. pub` dir in your project?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer how do you run pub command line things in Windows? I will try deleting the .pub now anyway.

Comment: Wait...I don't seem to have a .pub directory in my projects.

Comment: Just ensure you have the `dart-sdk/bin` directory in your path, open a shell and write the command.

Comment: So I changed directory as appropriate `cd Downloads\dart\dart-sdk\bin` and when trying to run `pub cache repair`I get pretty much the same error.

Comment: Would a fresh "install" of DartEditor help? I think I will try that quite soon when I get the chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so deleting the dart directory (the one with the editor executable, relevant .jar files and all that other stuff)  and downloading it anew did resolve my issue. I'm curious though as to whether anyone knows what might have caused the issue, and/or what other things I might have been able to do to resolve it.

Comment: I guess the previous downlod was somehow corrupted and Idoubt there was any other way to solve it.

Comment: That makes sense I guess. Who knows what might have gotten muddled up with the whole system restore process and whatnot. Oh well at least things in general seem ok.